# Subscription beyond count with bulk collect

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Hi I have a problem with the error: Subscription beyond count. I have a procedure that creates an order (for the clarity of the code this part is removed). Procedure picks the products from the basket and then lowers the quantity of the particular product in the warehouses (there can be 1 or more warehouses) in the loop. Can you please explain what am I doing wrong? Thanks a lot.

Here is the body of my procedure:

```
PROCEDURE cpr_create_order (pin_intCustomer       IN customer.customer_id%TYPE,
                            pin_strPayment        IN payment.payment_type%TYPE,
                            pin_strTransp         IN transp.transp_type%TYPE,
                            pout_strErrorCode     OUT NUMBER,
                            pout_strErrorMessage  OUT VARCHAR2)
IS

    lv_warehouse_balance    NUMBER;
    lv_intQuantity          NUMBER;
    lv_intOrder             NUMBER;
    
    TYPE collection_list IS TABLE OF NUMBER;
    lv_products     collection_list := collection_list();
    lv_quantities   collection_list := collection_list();
    
    lv_warehouses   collection_list := collection_list();
    lv_balances     collection_list := collection_list();
    
BEGIN
    pout_strErrorCode    := 0;
    pout_strErrorMessage := '';
    
    SAVEPOINT S1;
        
        -- fill collections of products and quantities from basket
        SELECT product_id, basket_quantity
        BULK COLLECT INTO lv_products, lv_quantities
        FROM basket
        WHERE order_id IS NULL
        ORDER BY product_id;
        
        FOR i IN 1.. lv_products.COUNT LOOP    -- 1
            
             -- fill collection of warehouses and actual product balances
             SELECT warehouse_id, product_balance  --1,2   -- 5,10
             BULK COLLECT INTO lv_warehouses, lv_balances
             FROM warehouse
             WHERE product_id = lv_products(i)
             ORDER BY warehouse_id;
             
             lv_intQuantity := lv_quantities(i);   --8
             
             FOR j IN 1..lv_warehouses.COUNT LOOP
                IF lv_intQuantity > 0 THEN
                    SELECT product_balance
                    INTO lv_warehouse_balance
                    FROM warehouse
                    WHERE product_id = lv_products(i)
                    AND warehouse_id = lv_warehouses(j);
                    
                    -- lower the balance of the product at the warehouse by the given quantity
                    IF lv_intQuantity < lv_warehouse_balance THEN   --8 --10
                        UPDATE warehouse
                        SET product_balance = product_balance - lv_intQuantity
                        WHERE product_id = lv_products(i)
                        AND warehouse_id = lv_warehouses(j);
                        
                        lv_intQuantity := lv_intQuantity - lv_intQuantity; -- 0
                    
                    -- remove product from the warehouse    
                    ELSIF lv_intQuantity >= lv_warehouse_balance THEN
                        DELETE FROM warehouse
                        WHERE product_id = lv_products(i)
                        AND warehouse_id = lv_warehouses(j);
                        
                        lv_intQuantity := lv_intQuantity - lv_balances(i);
                        
                    END IF;
                END IF;
             END LOOP;  
        END LOOP;     
    
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
      pout_strErrorCode := -1;
      pout_strErrorMessage  := substr(SQLERRM,
                                instr(SQLERRM, 'ORA') + 11,
                                length(SQLERRM));
      ROLLBACK TO S1;
END cpr_create_order;
```

Comment: what Oracle error are you getting ?

Comment: Subscription beyond count

Comment: this article will help you https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:9537826100346801764

Comment: When I loop through 1 product only it works ok. But when I loop through for example 3 products and each is stored in 2 warehouses then it creates the error subscription beyond count.

Comment: you should use different types for each collection, instead of the same for all of them

Comment: I tried creating separate collections for all 4 of them but I end up with same error.

Comment: I am going to try to replicate the issue. Can you post the DDL structure of the tables involved in the procedure ?

Comment: At what line is the error?

Comment: I would love to post it but they are not in english language :(

Comment: why do you have input parameters you are not using anywhere in the procedure ?

Comment: Because I removed the part of the code where I am actually creating an order. The error is at the block -- remove product from the warehouse at the line lv_intQuantity := lv_intQuantity - lv_balances(i); It then directly jumps to exception block. But this does not happen for first 2 products, only for the 3rd

Comment: Im using these test data: Product_id: 1, product quantity: 10, warehouse id: 1 (quantity 5), warehouse id: 2 (quantity 10); Product_id: 2, product quantity: 5, warehouse id: 1 (quantity 5), warehouse id: 2 (quantity 10);  Product_id: 3, product quantity: 10, warehouse id: 1 (quantity 5), warehouse id: 2 (quantity 10) .... product_id and product quantity are fields in the basket table

Comment: @AlexPoole, you are totally right. My mistake ;)

Comment: Thank you both for your help ! Very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
lv_intQuantity := lv_intQuantity - lv_balances(i);
```

should be:

```
lv_intQuantity := lv_intQuantity - lv_balances(j);
```

The `lv_products` and `lv_quantities` collections are populated by the first bulk collect, so they have the same number of members, and should be indexed by the same variable, `i` - which you are doing.

The `lv_warehouses` and `lv_balances` collections are populated by the second bulk collect, so they have the same number of members, and should be indexed by the same variable, `j`.

You should not refer to `lv_balances(i)` - it will give a result sometimes but it won't be what you expect, and when `j` is lower then `i` it will get this error as there is no member with index `i` in that collection.

Comment: Thank you Alex so so much! This solved the issue

Comment: @Alex Poole, well seen!